# RDP tsclient shared drive shortcuts

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, shortcuts

I'm connecting to a Windows Server 2008 machine via RDP and opt to share the C: drive of my local machine (running Win7.) This always works without issue. When I create a shortcut to something on that drive, say, \\tsclient\C\Jobs, it works fine until I log out. When I log in again, the shortcut does not work. There's no feedback, no 'folder can't be found, do you want to delete this shortcut?', nothing. I'm able to navigate to that directory manually, but the already created shortcut simply does not work anymore, and I'll need to recreate it each time I log in.

The only useful info I could find via Google was [this](http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-ts/11529/Shortcut-to-local-folder) thread, with the solution being to run a script upon login to recreate the shortcut. There's no way to do that with a batch file and I don't want to bother with much more than that so I thought I'd check if anyone had another solution to this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know of a way to fix this, but I can illuminate why it doesn't work. It seems that RDP makes the local drive have a different GUID every time when it connects. The system will view the drive as two seperate drives with a new connection. I don't see how this can be accomplished without a script to make a connection to a new folder every time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution to this [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29762050/shortcut-to-tsclient-destroyed-on-session-termination.aspx). Add "%windir%\explorer.exe " without the quotes, with the space, before the directory in the shortcut target.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this as well myself. Sorry to bring up an old post but John but, you helped me narrow this down further.

When adding %windir%\explorer.exe to the path, it wants to open a separate explorer window, which isn't too great when trying to use the shortcut in a save dialogue.

I found that after changing the shortcut to point to a local file (%windir%\explorer.exe), saving it, then changing it back to the original path that it all of a sudden starts working as expected.

Altering the link to that local file breaks that invisible GUID connection in the link and treats it as a regular link to a network share and the link then works between logins.

This helped greatly with our recent transition to OneDrive while using RemoteApps!

Answer (score 1):

OK, another work around using just the Windows GUI.

I created a shortcut "favourite" to a folder on a local drive. As per above, it didn't work when I came in on next session.

Then I edited the properties on the shortcut and removed the quotes from the "Target" property.  Then hit Apply and shortcut now works for all sessions.  Must have got rid of the hidden GUID mentioned in other posts.

I am using Win Server 2012 R2.